# Order Export File not showing line break

Tags: excel, csv, xlsx

I am using Wpallexport plugin to export orders in xlsx format. 
I have values in row with line break but it didnot display with line break. It displayed in a single line

[image]

But when i open same file in Goolge Spreadsheet it works perfect.

[image]

Can someone please help me to get the result as Google Spreadsheet.

Comment: Turn on Wrap Text